# Error while opening excel pivot table report from sharepoint 2010

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I made a pivot table report using excel 2010 that retrieving data from shareportint 2010 list, the report is working fine in excel but when I uploaded it to document library and put it in web part to view from share point it showing me this error :

```
Unable to refresh data for a data connection in the workbook. 
Try again or contact your system administrator. The following connections failed to refresh: 

owssvr[1]
```

what should I do to resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you inspect SharePoint's log files?

Comment: 1) Was there any interesting information in the log file? 2) Yes.

Comment: One more side note: This type of question is a better fit for sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You should refer to [this artice](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604007.aspx) in MSDN when working with external data connections within an Excel workbook. Before publishing the workbook into SharePoint you must make sure the connection belongs among the set of (administrator-defined) trusted connections.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error when trying to refresh data in an Excel Web Part using SharePoint 2010.

Here is the screenshot of my error:
[SharePoint Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L51sY.png)

My problem was that I was setting the source of the Excel Pivot tables directly to the SharePoint list. In order to get it to work I had to:

1. Go to the SharePoint list to be used as a data source
2. Select the "Export to Excel" button to obtain the .iqy file
3. Save this file then open it in Excel which will open the list in Excel
4. Any pivot tables created must then use this table as the source, not the connection that is found under the "existing connections" button in Excel